# My child, siblings and I

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I walk around my child, me and my siblings. One of us is too young and he is not one of us anymore. All my child does is sit there and wobble every so often, but he is the brightest of us all. I am one of a kind, and none of my siblings are like me, a lot of them are just full of hot air, but I fear the day when my child gets bigger and kills us all. I have been here for some time, but I won’t be here is a while.

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> Earth

Your child is

> the Sun

And your siblings are

> the other planets (and Pluto)

One of us is too young and he is not one of us anymore.

> Pluto got "demoted" to dwarf planet a while back

All my child does is sit there and wobble every so often, but he is the brightest of us all.

> The Sun is the bightest object in the sky.
>  Apparently, the Sun [wobbles](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/barycenter/en/) due to the planets' gravity

I am one of a kind, and none of my siblings are like me

> Earth is the only habitable planet

a lot of them are just full of hot air

> gas giants, Jupiter and Saturn

but I fear the day when my child gets bigger and kills us all

> The Sun will certainly swallow the Earth at some point

Comment: Well done Jafe! You are certainly very good at solving riddles!

Comment: @RohitJose Thanks! This was a fun one.

Comment: Well, this is just a thought, but... (ROT13) Gur Rnegu jba'g or fjnyybjrq ol gur Fha. V zrna, nf vg tebjf naq orpbzrf ovttre va fvmr, gung qbrf abg arprffnevyl zrna va orpbzrf ovttre va znff. Va snpg, gur znff qrpernfrf jura vgf fvmr vapernfrf. Naq, chefhnag gb Rvafgrva, vs gur znff qrpernfrf gura fb vgf qbrf gur fgeratgu tenivgngvbany svryq fheebhaqvat vg. Guvf zrnaf gung gurer zvtug or n punapr gung Rnegu'f beovg jvyy jvqra naq fcveny bhg jura gur Fha cnffrf whfg gur evtug fvmr, naq jr zvtug rfpncr orvat fjnyybjrq ol gur Fha! :D